# How to change mapsforge street names in .map file

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, mapsforge

I downloaded a map file (.map) from mapsforge server,
now how can I edit or add some information to this file?
for example I want to change some street names

Comment: I was hoping someone could tell me where to start
I searched but i found nothing about .map file editor program

Comment: But this is not a tutorial site. Show some meaningful code and illustrate where exactly you're stuck at. Then you'll get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this file follows the [OSM XML schema](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) then you can use [JOSM](http://josm.openstreetmap.de/) to edit it. But if you just want to change some street names then a simple text editor will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Does not change, you will need to edit the **.osm** file and then regenerate the **.map**.